# Getting Over-Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

I have a string list `List<string> mylist`.I have a background operation that adds strings to this list.
i use another background operation to process the strings in this list

```
foreach (string pfile in mylist) 
{
//dostuff
}
```

This results in this exception

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

I cannot fetch the full list of files before hitting the loop as a timer operation adds files to the list while the loop is running.How can i get around this problem.Please advice.

Comment: You may want to use [something other than `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to institute some kind of locking.

```
private object _locker = new object();  // Class member object

void ProcessList()  // Or whatever it's called
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        foreach (string pfile in mylist)
        {
            //dostuff
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you wrap the other thread's add activity in a `lock` also, using the same `_locker` object.

If the `//dostuff` code takes a long time, you might want to consider operating on a copy of the list to minimize the amount of time the list is locked:

```
    string[] mylistCopy;

    lock (_locker)
    {
        mylistCopy = mylist.ToArray();
    }

    foreach (string pfile in mylistCopy)
    {
        //dostuff
    }
```